# Why is there no error when the returned function is not being assigned?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm learning the concept of first class functions in Python (using Python 3.6.8) and couldn't figure out why code below doesn't show any errors.

```
def outer_fn(msg):
    def inner_fn():
        print(msg)
    return inner_fn


outer_fn("text")
```

Comment: What error do you expect, and why?

Comment: It's perfectly valid syntax, hence no error. In fact functions nested just like that are called `decorators`, you can read more about this [here](https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Decorators).

Answer (score 3):

Because it's a perfectly fine thing to do.

Sometimes you call a function for its *side effects* (it prints something, saves something to a database, changes some variable) and aren't interested in the return value. Python does not tell you to do anything with the return value, it just calls the function for you.

Answer (score 0):

It's not showing an error because your code doesnt have any errors,you need to call your inner function like:

```
outer = outer_fn("text")
outer() # call inner_fn
```

full code:

```
def outer_fn(msg): #outer function
    def inner_fn(): #inner function
        print(msg) #able to acces the variable of outer function
    return inner_fn


outer = outer_fn("text")
outer() # call inner_fn
```

output:

```
text
```